# firebase in react js app doesnt set auth object on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a simple react js app using firebase as an authentication tool. Here is my **app.js**

```
***some imports

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentUser: null
        }
    }

unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async  userAuth => {
        if(userAuth){
            const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
            userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
                this.setState({
                    currentUser: {
                        id: snapShot.id,
                        ...snapShot.data()
                    }
                },() => {console.log(this.state)});
            });

        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({ currentUser: userAuth });
            
        }

    });

}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
}



render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.currentUser.email}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
}





export default App
```

the problem is when i run the project, it gives this error `currentUser is null`  and if I remove the `<h1>{this.state.currentUser.email}</h1>` in app.jsx the console logs the state after 5 or 6 seconds delay and that log contains what I want, which is currentUser.

so this what I get when I run the project with `<h1>{this.state.currentUser.email}</h1>`

> TypeError: this.state.currentUser is null

And this is what i get **in console** when i remove`<h1>..</h1>` (after 5 or 6 second of waiting)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to access the email it does not exist yet. When your component is initialized render is called before componentDidMount. And you are trying to access email which still needs to be set on your state and hence you get the error.

You should use a conditional statement inside your render like

```js
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.currentUser && (<h1>{this.state.currentUser.email}</h1>))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This way your app won't break and you can even show some default UI to user by the time you get the data in the state from firebase.